# Is there a way to get a warning when a Scala Value Class needs to become instantiated?

Tags: scala, value-class

In the documentation about [Scala value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), it is mentioned that there are three cases when a value class needs to actually be allocated an instance:

> Allocation Summary
>
> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> 1. a value class is treated as another type.
> 2. a value class is assigned to an array.
> 3. doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Is there a setting in the compiler or in the language features which would produce a warning when a value class needs to be instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

No, not currently.

However, it is very rarely worth bothering with this kind of micro-optimisation.

If you have some very very hot code and you need to optimise it as far as possible then just try a few things and re-benchmark.

The JIT compiler will change what your code is doing at the machine level a lot of the time if the code is hot enough.

The overhead of allocating a value class is often not even measurable unless it is the only thing the thread is doing. See e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/XdQnbcs2SRM for some benchmarks where value class allocation is not measurable.